# Distinguishing between measurement outliers and unmodeled state dynamics in Kalman filter

Tags: hypothesis-testing, outliers, kalman-filter, anomaly-detection

Consider a linear Kalman filtering scenario with the following state update and measurement equations:
$$
\mathbf{x}(k+1) = \mathbf{F}(k) \mathbf{x}(k) + \mathbf{w}(k) \\
 \mathbf{z}(k) = \mathbf{H}(k) \mathbf{x}(k) + \mathbf{v}(k).
$$

It is well-known that $\chi^2$ type tests can be performed on the innovations sequence generated as part of the Kalman update equations to detect measurement outliers.   However, it would seem that such tests would trigger false alarms in the presence of occasional, unknown, and generally unmodeled high dynamics in the state update itself (e.g., a momentary increase in the covariance of the process noise $\mathbf{w}(k)$ or a brief increase in acceleration (2nd derivative) when using a constant-velocity (1st derivative) model).

My question is how in practice does one attempt to distinguish between between genuine measurement outliers (which should be suppressed) and a momentary increase in state variable dynamics (which the filter should be allowed to chase).